# Clojure: namespace metadata

Tags: clojure

How can I get namespace metadata? In repl I do:

```
=> (in-ns my.test)
#<Namespace my.test>
=> (meta *ns*)
{:a "hello"}
=> ; Return back to repl namespace:
   (in-ns 'user)
   ; Or use 'with-ns
```

My namespace definition is:

```
(ns ^{:a "hello"} my.test
  ...)
```

Any of `(meta #'my.test)` variants fail, although it works good for `def`-ined entities. I can understand that `(ns...)` doesn't define a variable and `*ns*` is a special var that I cannot reference outside, but I'm in doubt what really happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAICT there is a longstanding problem whereby metadata attached to symbolic names passed to `ns` forms is not properly attached to the namespace object.

As an alternative, you can pass additional arguments to `ns`:

```
(ns foo.core
  "This is foo.core's excellent docstring."
  {:interesting "piece of metadata"}
  (:require [bar.core :as bar]))
```

This style works as expected. I also happen to find it more aesthetically pleasing.

NB. other Clojure macros introducing named objects also tend to accept extra docstring / metadata arguments in this fashion:

```
(defn foo
  "A particularly lucid docstring for foo."
  {:trivia "The first function named foo was written in ..."}
  []
  ; ...
  )
```

Comment: Also, `(meta (the-ns 'foo.core))` or `(meta *ns*)` should work to retrieve the supplied metadata.

Comment: @Jared314 Ah yes, missed the part about `#'my.test`. Thanks! @demi `#'` is used to refer to Vars (it's shorthand for the `var` special form); for getting a namespace by name, you can use `the-ns` or `find-ns`.

Comment: From `(source the-ns)`: Namespace is separate entity which is not a variable, so why `#'my.test` doesn't work. But why `(meta 'my.test)` fails? From source - `the-ns` just assigns the type for `x` so proper branch in `meta` taken. With out this it's just a Symbol with no meta.

Comment: But why `(meta ^clojure.lang.Namespace 'my.test)` fails? Magic of `:static` attribute?

Comment: (1) `the-ns` checks if its argument is a namespace object. If so, it returns it; if not, it assumes that it's a symbol and uses `find-ns` to find a namespace of that name. In the latter case, if `find-ns` fails to find an appropriate namespace, `the-ns` throws an exception. (2) `(meta 'my.test)` asks about the metadata attached to the symbol `'my.test` (as returned by the reader). Here there's no metadata attached, so the correct return value is `nil`. (3) Hinting `'my.test` to `Namespace` makes no sense -- it's actually a symbol. (4) `#'my.test` is shorthand for `(var my.test)`.

Comment: Michal, I appreciate your answer! Thank you!